# Building a decryption function by CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, aes, cryptojs

I'm encountering a problem on building a decryption function by CryptoJS.

I've create an encryption string through the function create_mpg_aes_encrypt(), and trying to built another function create_mpg_aes_decrypt() to decrypt the string I generated.

However, I can't get the result I want.

On the other hands, I built a function create_aes_encrypt_try(), to test how CryptoJS work on decryption. I successfully got the result I want.
However, according to my observation, the parameter I pass into CryptoJS.AES.decrypt() isn't a string, but an array.

The function I want to build is for decrypting the string. Is there any way to parse the string or how could I build this function?

```
  //------------------Info--------------------------------------------------------------
let parameter = {
    MerchantID: "3430112",
    RespondType: "JSON",
    TimeStamp: "1485232229",
    Version: "1.4",
    MerchantOrderNo: "S_1485232229",
    Amt: 40,
    ItemDesc: "UnitTest",
}

//-------------------Encryption-------------------------------------------------------
const Hashkey = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
const HashIV = "1234567890123456";

const CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(Hashkey);
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(HashIV);
const encrypt_mode = {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
};

//-----------------------------Main---------------------------------------------------
let str = create_mpg_aes_encrypt(parameter, key, encrypt_mode);
//console.log(str);

let try_decryption = create_mpg_aes_encrypt_try(parameter, key, encrypt_mode);

let result = create_aes_decrypt(str, key, encrypt_mode);
console.log(result);
//-----------------------------Function-----------------------------------------------
function create_mpg_aes_encrypt(parameter, key, encrypt_mode){
    //URL ENCODED QUERY STRING
    let params = new URLSearchParams(parameter);
    let str = params.toString();
    str = addpadding(str);
    console.log(str, "\n");
    
    let encrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str, key, encrypt_mode);
    
    encrypted_data = encrypted_data.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    
    str = encrypted_data;
    str = str.trim();
    return str;
}

function hex2bin (s) {
  const ret = []
  let i = 0
  let l
  s += ''
  for (l = s.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    const c = parseInt(s.substr(i, 1), 16)
    const k = parseInt(s.substr(i + 1, 1), 16)
    if (isNaN(c) || isNaN(k)) return false
    ret.push((c << 4) | k)
  }
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, ret)
}

function addpadding(str){
    const blocksize = 32;
    let len = str.length;
    let pad = blocksize - (len % blocksize);
    let string = str;
    for(let i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
        string += String.fromCharCode(pad);
    }
    return string;
}

function create_aes_decrypt(tradeinfo, key, encrypt_mode) {
    let return_str = "";
    let decrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(tradeinfo, key, encrypt_mode);
    
    decrypted_data = decrypted_data.toString();
    //console.log(decrypted_data, "\n");
    
    return_str = decrypted_data;
    return return_str;
}

function create_mpg_aes_encrypt_try(parameter, key, encrypt_mode){
    // URL ENCODED QUERY STRING
    let params = new URLSearchParams(parameter);
    let str = params.toString();
    str = addpadding(str);
    
    let encrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str, key, encrypt_mode);
    let decrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_data, key, encrypt_mode);
    
    encrypted_data = encrypted_data.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    decrypted_data = decrypted_data.toString();
    decrypted_data = hex2bin(decrypted_data);
    
    console.log(encrypted_data, "\n");
    console.log(decrypted_data, "\n");
    
    str = encrypted_data;
    str = str.trim();
    return str;
}

    // The result I want
    /*the string going to be encrypted
MerchantID=3430112&RespondType=JSON&TimeStamp=1485232229&Version=1.4&MerchantOrderNo=S_1485232229&Amt=40&ItemDesc=UnitTest*/
    
    /*the string after encryption
ff91c8aa01379e4de621a44e5f11f72e4d25bdb1a18242db6cef9ef07d80b0165e476fd1d9acaa53170272c82d122961e1a0700a7427cfa1cf90db7f6d6593bbc93102a4d4b9b66d9974c13c31a7ab4bba1d4e0790f0cbbbd7ad64c6d3c8012a601ceaa808bff70f94a8efa5a4f984b9d41304ffd879612177c622f75f4214fa*/
    /* After Decryption
MerchantID=3430112&RespondType=JSON&TimeStamp=1485232229&Version=1.4&MerchantOrderNo=S_1485232229&Amt=40&ItemDesc=UnitTest*/
```

The following is the php reference code I wanted to realized

```
function create_aes_decrypt($parameter = "", $key = "", $iv = "") {
return openssl_decrypt(hex2bin($parameter),'AES-256-CBC', 
$key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA|OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
```

}

Comment: Just a general note: encryption works with binary data and not with strings. If your input is a string (or e.g. a json-object/string) you need to transform it to a binary form before encryption (e.g. using CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse). The **output** of an encryption function is not suitable for a regular string (think of hex x00's) as a lot of data is not printable. To get a string encoding for transport or storage, better use a **Base64 encoding** on the output and before decryption run a **Base64 decoding**. Sometimes the output is a "hex encoded string" - then run a hex to binary conversion.

Comment: @MichaelFehr - Where _exactly_ do you see an issue? The JavaScript object _is_ serialized, the ciphertext _is_ hex encoded, and passing a string as plaintext _is allowed_ for `CryptoJS.AES.encrypt()`. However, its output _must not_ simply be Base64 or hex encoded, since it's a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Topaco: I do not see a problem within the codes (that's why I wrote "in general"). To me it looked like the OP was a little bit confused about the different input types of his own functions.

Comment: @MichaelFehr - Ah, OK, but kinda confusing, expecting to find one of the listed problems in the code (wasn't sure I missed something), thx.

Comment: @Topaco: Actually I am kinda confusing about the relation about the different encoding method in CryptoJS. Is there any material for beginner to understand that. I've been watching the CryptoJS document, but I can only understand it through trail and error.

Comment: @MichaelFehr: I guess that's why you see different input types of my own functions.

Comment: What exactly is unclear (_encoding_ is a broad field)?  If you refer to encoders, try e.g. [this](https://www.davidebarranca.com/2012/10/crypto-js-tutorial-cryptography-for-dummies/). Otherwise it would be best if you post a question on SO and describe the problem in detail. However, make sure that a reference to programming is recognizable, otherwise the question might be closed (be aware that questions about tutorials, books etc. are off topic on SO). I.e. post e.g. an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and test data so that the problem is comprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decryption fails because `CryptoJS.AES.decrypt()` requires a `CipherParams` object:

```
{ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(ciphertextHex)}
```

where `ciphertextHex` is the hex encoded ciphertext. If you fix this, decryption works. This is shown in the JavaScript below.

```js
  //------------------Info--------------------------------------------------------------
let parameter = {
    MerchantID: "3430112",
    RespondType: "JSON",
    TimeStamp: "1485232229",
    Version: "1.4",
    MerchantOrderNo: "S_1485232229",
    Amt: 40,
    ItemDesc: "UnitTest",
}

//-------------------Encryption-------------------------------------------------------
const Hashkey = "12345678901234567890123456789012";
const HashIV = "1234567890123456";

const key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(Hashkey);
const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(HashIV);
const encrypt_mode = {
    iv: iv,
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
};

//-----------------------------Main---------------------------------------------------
let str = create_mpg_aes_encrypt(parameter, key, encrypt_mode);

let try_decryption = create_mpg_aes_encrypt_try(parameter, key, encrypt_mode);

let result = create_aes_decrypt(str, key, encrypt_mode);
document.getElementById("pt_3").innerHTML = result;
//-----------------------------Function-----------------------------------------------
function create_mpg_aes_encrypt(parameter, key, encrypt_mode){
    //URL ENCODED QUERY STRING
    let params = new URLSearchParams(parameter);
    let str = params.toString();
    str = addpadding(str);
    document.getElementById("pt_1").innerHTML = str;
    
    let encrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str, key, encrypt_mode);
    
    encrypted_data = encrypted_data.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    
    str = encrypted_data;
    str = str.trim();
    return str;
}

function hex2bin (s) {
  const ret = []
  let i = 0
  let l
  s += ''
  for (l = s.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    const c = parseInt(s.substr(i, 1), 16)
    const k = parseInt(s.substr(i + 1, 1), 16)
    if (isNaN(c) || isNaN(k)) return false
    ret.push((c << 4) | k)
  }
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(String, ret)
}

function addpadding(str){
    const blocksize = 32;
    let len = str.length;
    let pad = blocksize - (len % blocksize);
    let string = str;
    for(let i = 0; i < pad; i++) {
        string += String.fromCharCode(pad);
    }
    return string;
}

function create_aes_decrypt(tradeinfo, key, encrypt_mode) {
    let return_str = "";
    
    /*
    let decrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(tradeinfo, key, encrypt_mode);        
    decrypted_data = decrypted_data.toString();
    */
    // Fix
    let decrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt({ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(tradeinfo)}, key, encrypt_mode);
    decrypted_data = decrypted_data.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    
    return_str = decrypted_data;
    return return_str;
}

function create_mpg_aes_encrypt_try(parameter, key, encrypt_mode){
    // URL ENCODED QUERY STRING
    let params = new URLSearchParams(parameter);
    let str = params.toString();
    str = addpadding(str);
    
    let encrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(str, key, encrypt_mode);
    let decrypted_data = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted_data, key, encrypt_mode);
    
    encrypted_data = encrypted_data.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
    decrypted_data = decrypted_data.toString();
    decrypted_data = hex2bin(decrypted_data);
    
    document.getElementById("ct_2").innerHTML = encrypted_data;
    document.getElementById("pt_2").innerHTML = decrypted_data;
   
    str = encrypted_data;
    str = str.trim();
    return str;
}

// The result I want
/*the string going to be encrypted
MerchantID=3430112&RespondType=JSON&TimeStamp=1485232229&Version=1.4&MerchantOrderNo=S_1485232229&Amt=40&ItemDesc=UnitTest*/
    
/*the string after encryption
ff91c8aa01379e4de621a44e5f11f72e4d25bdb1a18242db6cef9ef07d80b0165e476fd1d9acaa53170272c82d122961e1a0700a7427cfa1cf90db7f6d6593bbc93102a4d4b9b66d9974c13c31a7ab4bba1d4e0790f0cbbbd7ad64c6d3c8012a601ceaa808bff70f94a8efa5a4f984b9d41304ffd879612177c622f75f4214fa*/
/* After Decryption
MerchantID=3430112&RespondType=JSON&TimeStamp=1485232229&Version=1.4&MerchantOrderNo=S_1485232229&Amt=40&ItemDesc=UnitTest*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="pt_1"></p>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="ct_2"></p>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="pt_2"></p>
<p style="font-family:'Courier New', monospace;" id="pt_3"></p>
```

---

Currently, when encrypting with the CryptoJS code, you use PKCS7 padding over a block size of 32 bytes, which is inefficient for AES with a block size of 16 bytes.
When decrypting with the PHP code (and therefore also with the CryptoJS code), the padding is disabled, i.e. not removed, which is rather unusual for PKCS7.
So it's unclear whether the correct padding is used for encryption in the CryptoJS code. Therefore, you should check for encryption if the padding used in the CryptoJS code really matches that of the PHP code.